# Prove that there is a closed geodesic in the "inside" of a torus

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, curvature, geodesic

> I want to show that there exists a closed geodesic on an arbitrarily chosen surface where the Gaussian curvature is negative (on the entire surface).

One example would be the "inside" of a ring Torus,
where the Gaussian curvature is:

$K = \frac{\cos(v)}{a(c+a\cos(v))} <0$ for $v \in(\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{2}) $

I'm confident that there has to be a closed geodesic because of its symmetry but I'm not sure how to prove it.

Comment: Here is an idea: one can show that if $(M,g)$ is a Riemannian manifold, then in every free-homotopy class $C\in \pi_1(M)$, there is a geodesic. Thus, if your surface is not simply-connected, this shows that there exists a closed geodesic.

Comment: Hint: If $M$ is a Riemannian manifold and $s: M\to M$ is an isometry then the fixed-point set of $s$ is totally geodesic. On the other hand, if your surface is simply-connected and negatively curved then there are no (nonconstant) closed geodesics.

Comment: I am confused. Are you trying to find one surface with such a closed geodesic? Or you want to find such a closed geodesic for each given surface?

Comment: @ArcticChar I just want to prove that there exists at least one closed geodesic for an arbitrary surface with negative gaussian curvature, I just chose the inside of a torus because that was the first thing that came up to my mind

Comment: Okay... But your example (the "ring" torus) do not have negative curvature on the entire surface. Indeed such a surface cannot be embedded in $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: @ArcticChar Yes you are right but I'm not looking at the entire torus only for the values between pi/2 and 3pi/2 where the curvature is negative. Maybe I should have called it half-torus

Comment: Also, the hyperbolic plane is a negatively curved surface with no closed geodesic. What you said is true for *compact* and closed negatively curved surfaces.

Comment: Well, you have to modify your question. As stated it is quite trivially false (say, without the compactness condition)

Comment: If the manifold is not simply connected and the geodesic curvature of the boundary has the right sign or is zero, then there is a length-minimizing geodesic in the interior.